# Rails 3: Putting a single quote ' in a form (escape character?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, escaping

Having trouble figuring out how to put a single quote in my view.

```
<td><%= link_to 'This guy's blog', blog_path %></td>
```

Did a quick google trying to figure out what character escapes a single quote and came up with nothing.

Little help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<td><%= link_to 'This guy\'s blog', blog_path %></td>
```

Or just change to double quotes:

```
<td><%= link_to "This guy's blog", blog_path %></td>
```

Comment: Tried the backslash \ which might not have been picked up by gedit's code highlighting.

Gonna use double quotes.  Thanks!